# Where is login page defined in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

I've created .NET Core 5.0 Blazor WebAssembly hosted in ASP .NET Core.
Multiple views are missing but they application works. In particular the whole login page is missing and I can't forgot password page defined. How can I override them?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

They're 'hidden'.  Provided by Identity as part of the framework.  To get the pages into your project so that you can customise them:

1. Right-Click Server Project
2. Select Add > New Scaffold Item
3. Select "Identity"

You'll then get a load of new assets loaded into your Server project.  Look for:

Areas > Identity > Pages > Account > Login.cshtml

Customise away!